# Bootstrap collapse / hide when click outside with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a portfolio page where I'm trying to use bootstrap's collapse function. It works fine, but when one of divs is open and you click on another, the first one stays open and so on! I can leave it like that but it just looks bad. :)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project-1">
 <figure><img src="images/work/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></figure>
</a>
```

And the collapse div:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="project-info collapse animated fadeInRightBig" id="project-1">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <figure><img src="images/work/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></figure>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project-1">Close</button>
        <h3>This is My Project Description</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are a few thumbnails in orders like project-1, project-2, project-3.

Comment: sounds like you're looking for accordion functionality: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap 3, you just need to make sure all collapses are inside the same `.panel-group`.

See [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) in the Bootstrap 3 docs.

Like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/QAyLj/)

Comment: Thank you Joshua. Well,this is one of the solutions,to use accordions (right now Im not..Im using simple data-toggle="collapse") but then I need to rewrite all code.I thought there was a simple solution using jquery.Thanks